# How do you construct a singleton in dawn4?

Tags: dawn-4.0, singleton, constructor

Looks like they changed the constructor for singletons or I am doing this incorrectly.  Can anyone advise?

```
#include <eosiolib/eosio.hpp>
#include <eosiolib/singleton.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace eosio;


class simple: public contract {
public:
    simple(account_name self) : contract(self) {}

    void init(account_name key) {
        require_auth(_self);
        require_auth(key);

        // THIS DOESN'T WORK!
        AppSettings(N(simple)).set(AppConfig{key});
    }

private:
    struct AppConfig {
        account_name key;

        account_name primary_key() const { return key; }
        EOSLIB_SERIALIZE(AppConfig, (key))
    };


    typedef singleton<N(simple), N(appconfig),
                      N(simple), AppConfig   >   AppSettings;
};

EOSIO_ABI(simple, (init))
```

I am getting this in return:

```
simple.cpp:8:9: error: no matching conversion for functional-style cast from 'uint64_t'
      (aka 'unsigned long long') to 'AppSettings' (aka 'singleton< ::eosio::string_to_name("simple"),
      ::eosio::string_to_name("appconfig"), ::eosio::string_to_name("simple"), simple::AppConfig>')
        AppSettings(N(simple)).set(AppConfig{key});
```

Comment: Figured it out, the syntax should just be:

   `AppSettings().set(AppConfig{key});`

No arguments needed.  Is there a way to query this from `cleos`?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you are trying to do , so I just made it compile for you.

`template<uint64_t SingletonName, typename T>
   class singleton`

first parameter is N(simple) e.g. singleton name , second is a C++ type this singleton holds

**Singleton constructor** 
Say if scope and code is the same and same as owner of a contract then use `contract::_self` or simply _self because contract is a base class.

```
/**
      * Construct a new singleton object given the table's owner and the scope
      * 
      * @brief Construct a new singleton object
      * @param code - The table's owner
      * @param scope - The scope of the table
      */
     singleton( account_name code, scope_name scope ) : _t( code, scope ) {}
```

**singleton.set() function**

```
/**
          * Set new value to the singleton table
          * 
          * @brief Set new value to the singleton table
          * 
          * @param value - New value to be set
          * @param bill_to_account - Account to pay for the new value
          */
         void set( const T& value, account_name bill_to_account ) {
```

I am not sure if this is what you are looking for but I made your example compile

```
#include <eosiolib/eosio.hpp>
#include <eosiolib/singleton.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace eosio;


class simple: public contract {
public:
    simple(account_name self) : contract(self) {}

    void init(account_name key) {
        require_auth(_self);
        require_auth(key);

        // THIS WORKS!!!!!!
        AppSettings{_self, _self}.set(AppConfig{key}, N(simple));
    }

private:
    struct AppConfig {
        account_name key;

        account_name primary_key() const { return key; }
        EOSLIB_SERIALIZE(AppConfig, (key))
    };


    typedef singleton<N(simple), AppConfig>   AppSettings;
};
```